# AWS Elastic Beanstalk ASP.Net app failing because of Procfile error 'failed to generate rsyslog file with error Procfile could not be parsed'

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a WebApp I am trying to deploy using Elastic Beanstalk. I have set up a code pipeline to my github repo and code build to build it. The build succeeds, but at the last part of the pipeline (the deploy), there is a failure and the logs say the error is

`web: dotnet ./DiscoverOnDemand.dll`

I have looked at fellow developers procfiles and mine does not seem to be any different, yet I cannot get it working. Does anyone have any ideas?

Procfile
https://github.com/JerryKumarNZ/DiscoverOnDemand/blob/main/Procfile

I have checked the procfile for extra newlines but there were none, and I can't find any online resource that will 'check procfile' for me

Answer (score 1):

Found the reason, in Rider and I couldn't see it, but when I went to edit the file in GitHub I could see a space at the start before `web`. Removing this fixed the issue, still not sure why it was invisible in Rider